# Implementation of GestureDetectorCompat

Tags: android, gesture, usb-debugging

I have implemented a few gesture and touch control methods, But for some reason the app is installed but it doesnt seem to work. i.e the text doesnt change from the default one.
I am using an actual device connected to my pc( testing via usb debugging). Thanks for the help.

```
package com.example.kheriaa.gestures;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
    private TextView mainMessage;
    private GestureDetectorCompat myGestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainMessage =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MainMessage);
        this.myGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        myGestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        mainMessage.setText("onSingleTapConfirmed");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        mainMessage.setText("Double");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed to dispatch touch events to your `GestureDetector`. Add that function to your view:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    this.myGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Refering to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect):

> `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` notifies users when a particular
>   touch event has occurred. To make it possible for your `GestureDetector`
>   object to receive events, you override the View or Activity's
>   `onTouchEvent()` method, and pass along all observed events to the
>   detector instance.

Now, it should works fine.

**EDIT:** Add this function to your `View`, not to your `Activity` directly!

Comment: Error:(74, 12) error: class, interface, or enum expected. This error is thrown for every line of the above implementation

Comment: 6 months later: do you still consider my answer as a wrong answer?

Comment: Why not add it to the activity directly? Will it work if you do that?